# Allow pass to func only pointer, not values

Tags: go

I want to allow pass to func only pointer to a struct, restrict values. Is it possible?

What I want to do:

```golang
Foo(&Bar{}) // allowed
Foo(Bar{}) // IDE/compilation error
```

Actually i'm using signature like `func Foo(bar any)` which allows pass to the function any interface and type, of course, so in some cases it can cause problems.

Amount of types, which can passed to this function is should be not limited, and I don't want to use specific interface etc. Maybe this can be achieved with generics? But I'm not sure how to do it correctly.

I'm use go 1.18.

Comment: What is not working? Your cited `func Foo(bar any)` should work for both use cases

Comment: I mean that I want restrict usage of ```Foo(Bar{})```, allow only ```Foo(&Bar{})```, where Bar can be any struct type. Answer below helps in my case.

Comment: to limit to pointers of structs - you'd need to use runtime checks and use `reflect` package. `any` will allow any type e.g. `bool`, `*int32` - so no necessarily `struct`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use generics like this:

```golang
func Foo[T any](t *T){
…
}
```

Comment: Yes, looks like it works, thanks. I just forgot to mention that I also want to use this func as a method, but now I think I dont need a method like this. :)

Only one more question: in this case in func will be passed type *interface{}, not interface{}, is there some corner cases, when it can be a problem?

Comment: There is almost never a use case for a pointer to an interface. It's tempting to try `func xyz[T *any](v T)` - but this will not work.

Comment: But I'm need to reflect type of t in my func, so it still works fine with this answer. But maybe it is better idea to make whole thing with reflection, including this check, as you mentioned in comments above, thx.

Comment: Perhaps you need to wait until go 1.19

Comment: The requirement of “pointer to structs” is weird. I can create a type derived from int and add methods/implement interface. In many aspects with same behaviour as structs